# Questions on AWS Gateway Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-elb

Have a few questions regarding the GWLB behavior and limitations. Confirming these before I design a customer solution based on GWLB:

1. Per *GWLBe* the bandwidth limit is 40Gbps per the documentation. My need is 300Gbps (my appliance farm is to do 300Gbps). Can I create multiple (say 8, can become 16) GWLBe (all connected to the same GWLB) in *a single VPC* and spray across them to get to my need of 300Gbps? The only other constraint I see is the number of endpoints per VPC which is documented to be 50. Any reason this would fail?
2. For a given flow, suppose that the GWLB picks target=A.The nature of my appliance application is such that it is possible that the packet comes back to the GWLB from target=B (where B != A). Will this break the GWLB? Is there any assumption in the GWLB that a packet sent to a target must be returned from the same target?
3. For setting the idle timeout for GWLB, is the method the same as for other ELBs? Is the range from 0-4000 secs for this too?
4. Lastly, I am familiar that GWLB will send bidirectional flows to the same target. Does this make any assumption on which GWLBe the 2 directions entered the GWLB from? I don't see any -- confirming cuz in my case the 2 directions will enter from different GWLBe

Thanks for your comments
-Venky